# Extract a value from a text file in a specific position

Tags: bash-scripting

I have a file containing tons of information. It looks like this:

```
===============================================================================


   NSTEP       ENERGY          RMS            GMAX         NAME    NUMBER
     52      -4.8969E+05     5.1393E+00     1.7327E+03     P1         31

 BOND    =    29534.6906  ANGLE   =     2139.5547  DIHED      =     9235.7381
 VDWAALS =    51148.8783  EEL     =  -595288.4773  HBOND      =        0.0000
 1-4 VDW =     2741.3848  1-4 EEL =    26043.4789  RESTRAINT  =       29.3591
 DFTBESCF=   -15274.2075
 EAMBER  =  -489718.9594
 NMR restraints: Bond =    0.000   Angle =     0.000   Torsion =     0.000
===============================================================================
```

Now, I want to extract (and put in one column only) the value (here shown as -4.8969E+05) from the 'Energy' (or second) column in the line directly under the word `ENERGY`.

I tried to extract it with `grep` but have not been able to.

Comment: I made your question somewhat readable. Take it as an example and improve further ([edit]) if needed. In particular: do these `===` belong to the file? do `**` belong? Also please note we are not a script writing service, some research effort is required. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please click on `edit` above to the left, and add to your original post what we have asked for. Is the file you are trying to extract from tabulated; do {TAB} characters separate the columns, or are they separated by a number of spaces? If you can upload a sample file to someplace like Google Drive and share the URL so we might download it, that would speed resolution. Please also include what you tried with  grep so far; it is far easier for us to fix a broken script than to write from scratch.

Comment: If the file contains only space delimiters (no tabs, no back-spaces), then you should be able to use `cut -c M-N` to extract the columns you want, with some additional filters to remove the non-columnar data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be saying “I want the second field from the line
immediately after the line that contains the word `ENERGY`
(in which `ENERGY` is the second field).” 
If that’s what you want, you can do it with

```
awk '/ENERGY/ { found_it=1; next;     }
    found_it  { print $2; found_it=0; }'
```

(Put your filename at the end of that command — right after the `}'` —
or pipe your data into the above command.)

This simply

- Looks for a line that contains the string `ENERGY`,

  - sets a flag (`found_it`) when it does,
  - and skips that line.
- When it encounters a line, and the `found_it` flag is set,
  that means that the previous line contained `ENERGY`, so

  - print the second word from that line, and
  - clear (zero) the `found_it` flag, so we don’t produce output
    from any subsequent lines.

If you file has `ENERGY` on lines 4, 14 and 24,
then the above command will print the second field
from lines 5, 15 and 25. 
If that’s not what you want, a simpler approach is

```
awk '/ENERGY/ { found_it=1; next; }
    found_it  { print $2;   exit; }'
```

which is the same as the first one,
except, after it has printed the second field from line 5,
it just stops looking. 
Even if `ENERGY` appears only once in the file,
this approach is preferable in that
it doesn’t require reading the entire file,
but only up to the value you want.

These commands will:

- find the string `ENERGY` even if it is part of a larger word,
  such as `CENERGY`, `ENERGY-CONSUMING`, `ENERGYLEVEL` or `HIGH-ENERGY`.
- find the string `ENERGY`
  even if it is not the second field on its line.
- print the value of the second field,
  not the field where it found `ENERGY`.
- ***not*** find `Energy` or `energy`.
- fail silently if `ENERGY` is on the last line.

If those are problems,
edit your question to specify your requirements.

Comment: It works greatly! I was getting crazy with awk! Thanks a lot for your precious effort and time! You made my day! :)